# Timestamp, timedelta and conversion in Python

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, timedelta

I have a dataframe which has a timestamp column in the format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS:sss. Example is shown below:

```
0      2019-12-17 21:17:39.424
1      2019-12-17 21:17:41.065
2      2019-12-17 21:18:06.640
3      2019-12-17 21:18:07.229
4      2019-12-17 21:18:07.858
                 ...          
1072   2019-12-17 22:54:54.052
1073   2019-12-17 22:54:56.075
1074   2019-12-17 22:55:23.040
1075   2019-12-17 22:55:23.040
1076   2019-12-17 22:55:26.363
Name: time_stamp, Length: 1077, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

there are more than thousands of rows that I am reading from a csv file. What I have been trying to find the time interval (timedelta) between each successive timestamp. Since there difference between every successive pair is not greater than few seconds, I just want to retrieve that part (discarding the data, hour and minutes parts, which are 0 anyway.

I can perform the simple subtraction iteratively inside a loop, but the result that i get is a string for each calculation. Example is shown below:

```
> 0       0 days 00:00:03.988000
1       0 days 00:00:01.641000
2       0 days 00:00:25.575000
3       0 days 00:00:00.589000
4       0 days 00:00:00.629000
                 ...          
1072    0 days 00:00:36.084000
1073    0 days 00:00:02.023000
1074    0 days 00:00:26.965000
1075           0 days 00:00:00
1076    0 days 00:00:03.323000
Name: arr_time, Length: 1077, dtype: object
```

Now, as you can see, the datatype is string which prevents me performing various operations related to timedelta or datetime datatype. I am unable to change its datatype. I am so confused between *datetime*, *timestamp* and *timedelta* concepts that I can not figure out what operations or methods are supported for each case.

I can provide the raw csv file.

Can some please help me in just retrieving the *seconds* and *milliseconds* parts of each *timedelta* values into a Series or Dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data contains date/time information (for example as a string like "2019-12-17T21:17:39.424") - you parse that to `datetime` e.g. like

```
df['time_stamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_stamp'])
# gives dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

An individual element of this column (pd.Series) would be a `Timestamp`. If you subtract two timestamps from one another, you get a `timedelta`:

```
# the difference between timestamps are timedeltas:
df['dt'] = df['time_stamp'].diff()
# df['dt']
# 0                      NaT
# 1   0 days 00:00:01.641000
# 2   0 days 00:00:25.575000
# 3   0 days 00:00:00.589000
# 4   0 days 00:00:00.629000
# Name: dt, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Now that you have a column of dtype timedelta, you can work with that to get seconds and milliseconds:

```
# get the seconds fraction by flooring the total_seconds() of the timedelta
df['dt_s'] = np.floor(df['dt'].dt.total_seconds())
# df['dt_s']
# 0     NaN
# 1     1.0
# 2    25.0
# 3     0.0
# 4     0.0
# Name: dt_s, dtype: float64

# get the milliseconds by converting total_seconds() to milliseconds and taking modulo 1000:
df['dt_ms'] = (df['dt'].dt.total_seconds()*1000) % 1000
# df['dt_ms']
# 0      NaN
# 1    641.0
# 2    575.0
# 3    589.0
# 4    629.0
# Name: dt_ms, dtype: float64
```

If desired, you could format the seconds and millisecond components to a string column:

```
# format to ss:fff output:
df['s_ms'] = (df['dt_s'].fillna(0).apply(lambda s: f'{int(s):02d}') + 
              ':' + 
              df['dt_ms'].fillna(0).apply(lambda s: f'{int(s):03d}'))
# df['s_ms'] 
# 0    00:000
# 1    01:641
# 2    25:575
# 3    00:589
# 4    00:629
# Name: s_ms, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works perfectly.
One more question: how to represent resulting seconds and milliseconds values combined as [SS.mmm]?

Thank you once again.

Comment: @SaqibAlikhan: added an option to do so.